# Only one solution proofs

Tags: functions, derivatives, continued-fractions

I have $2$ questions in my homework that I can not figure out how to deal with:

> $1.$ Let $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $a>1$ and $0<b \leq 1$. Prove that $a x=b \sin x+c$ has one solution.

For the first question I understand I need to use Intermediate value theorem, but how? $x \mapsto a x$ is continuous and $x \mapsto  b \sin x$ is in range of $(-b,b)$. So there must be a one point of intersection but how do I prove it ?

> $2.$ Let $f$ be a continuous function between $[a,b]$ and differentiable between $(a,b)$. Assume that  $f^2(b)-f^2(a)=b^2-a^2$. Prove there exists $x\in(a,b)$ s.t. $f^′(x)f(x)-x=0$.
> *hint given*: $g(x)=f^2(x)-x^2$

For the second question I have no idea how to even approach it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: And please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @KingLogic I have edited the question thank you

Comment: @Axel done, thank you.

Comment: @models4fun Great! I tried to help you with editing a bit, but I do not understand the second question. What do you need to prove?

Comment: What is the _median_ theorem? Should not it be the _mean value_ theorem?

Comment: @Axel I'm sorry i meant Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Axel in second question I need to prove the last equation is true based on the given data.

Comment: Ok but what does $f^-(x)$ mean?

Comment: @Axel I have edited that, didn't know how to sign differentiable function. sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you made the effort of editing your post and include some of your thoughts, I will give you some hints:

**First question:**
Let $f : x \mapsto ax-b\sin(x)$, notice that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ by showing $f'>0$. Now what is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ and $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$? Can you finish this using the intermediate value theorem?

**Second question:** using the hint given, $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and its derivative is given by $g'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)-2x$. Now the assumption tells you that $g(a)=g(b)$ so try to use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: thank you, just solved the first question with your help on to the next one :)

Comment: second one sold as well TAHNK YOU !

Comment: I'm glad I could help!